# chrome popup extension not sending data on the api.php file

Tags: ajax, api, google-chrome

I am using chrome popup extension but no data is sent to the php file named api.php.I have searched on stackoverflow and found ajax related content but nothing is working.here is my popover.js file which uses ajax.I used $_POST['data'] to grab the data in api.php file

```
var api_url = "https://localhost/psol/api.php";

window.onload = function () {
    $("#checkout_btn").click(function () {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            'btnClicked': true
        }, function () {});
    });

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
            console.log(request);

            if (request.message === "show-loading") {
                $(".psol-button").addClass('hide');
                $(".psol-loader").removeClass("hide");
            }

            if (request.message === "hide-loading") {
                $(".psol-button").removeClass('hide');
                $(".psol-loader").addClass("hide");
            }

            if (request.message === "post-cart") {
                console.log(request.data);

                alert(JSON.stringify(request.data));

                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                    'postCartDone': true,
                    'redirectTo': api_url
                }, function () {});

                $.ajax({
                    url: api_url,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: request.data,
                    // data:{name:'uzair'},
                    success: function (result) {
                        // alert("all done");
                        console.log(1, result);
                    }

                }).done(function (result) {
                    console.log(2, result);
                    if (result.cartCount === 0) {
                        alert('There are no items in cart to checkout');
                    }else {
                        alert("this is also redirect");
                    }
                 });

            }

        });
};
```